# Site refused to connect on IIS Publish

Tags: hosting, iis-express, asp.net-core-3.0

I am publishing an ASP.Net Core 3.0 application in IIS. My publish profile looks like
[image: publish profile]

This is how my web.config file is in publish folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Application.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

In IIS, I created an Application Pool, set its CLR Version to **No Managed Code**, created a site with newly added Application pool and pointed towards folder in which file was published . I have hosting bundled installed
[image: hosting bundle]

When I browse application through IIS,
[image: error]

Url is redirected to login page but error is shown. Thanks in advance !!

**Edit 1:** On viewing Asp.Net Core Diagnostics from Jexus Manager

[image: view in jexus manager]

**Edit 2:** On viewing Asp.Net Core Diagnostics from Jexus Manager (IIS)
[image]

Edit 3:Binding diagnostics:
[image]

Comment: If you run the report, the cause should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi, ASP.NET Core module is not installed as part of IIS  is shown but as you can see in the image above, module is installed.

Comment: Edit the question to include the report.

Comment: @LexLi have a look

Comment: Note that you didn’t run the report against your IIS site, but an IIS Express site.

Comment: @LexLi sir, I have updated the question

Comment: Then ASP.NET Core seems to be configured properly for this IIS site. Check its site bindings with another report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi I have updated question to include binding diagnostics. Doesnot seem to be an issue

Comment: Well, that actually tells the issue. You bind the site to HTTP port 443 and try to access it in browser at HTTP port 80.

Comment: I am broswing website through IIS sir. Even if I change port 443 while browsing, issue still remains

Comment: You have a few options to go. 1) Configure the site to bind to HTTP with another port (such as 8080). Using 443 won't work because Windows/IIS should already use 443 for HTTPS (IIS Manager should prevent you from using 443 for HTTP but it doesn't). 2) Bind this site to HTTPS port 443, and then in browser you use `https://localhost/......`